# Get field value from form with busboy

Tags: node.js, forms, busboy

How do i retrieve a single field value from the "val" param with busboy?

.js

```
app.post('/somewhere', (req, res) => {
    req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
       //var foo = val.name;
       //var bar = val.number;
    });
});
```

.html

```
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="tel" name="number"><br>
```

According to [busboy git](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy):

> field [...] Emitted for each new non-file field found.

Using the provided example, i was able to identify that 'var' consists of two strings:

```
typeof(val) 

string
string
```

But after that i'm clueless in:

1. What is val in this scope? A var? array? something else?
2. How do i acess a specific element from val? Like the 'name' field.

Comment: Why do you access it with `req.busboy`? Have you attached it as a `req` property in a previous middleware?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Busboy works with events, so the proper way to get a specific element from your form is to implement on your own a structure that holds form data.

```js
app.post('/somewhere', (req, res) => {

  let formData = new Map();
  req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
    formData.set(fieldname, val);
  });

  req.busboy.on("finish", function() {

    console.log(formData) // Map { 'name' => 'hi', 'number' => '4' }
    // here you can do 
    formData.get('name') //  'hi'
    formData.get('number') //  '4'

    // any other logic with formData here

    res.end()
  });
});
```

I am not sure what you mean with `typeof val` but in my case, `val` is always a simple **string**

Comment: why did you use a Map here rather than just a straight object? I thought a Map had to have consistency in it's stored types, whereas a form might include all kinds of stuff...

Comment: Sure, it could be a plain object. I used a Map in order to have a similar API as [browser's formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for uniformity reasons. Also I don't think Maps have to have only one type of data, in fact they can have anything even functions as keys.